# How do I disable the vga cursor in long mode

Tags: assembly, x86, att, vga

I'm trying to write a game (without os, just boot into game) in assembly while in long mode. The university provides a kernel to use for the game that switches the cpu to long mode, therefore I can't use int 0x10. Now I'm testing some things out, but I'm not able to change any of the registers of the vga card (in bochs). 
This is what I tried to disable the cursor:

```
// set dx to index register
movw $0x3b4, %dx
// set index to 0x0a for cursor start register
movb $0x0a, %al
outb %dx

// set rax to zero
xorq %rax, %rax

// write value
movw $0x3b5, %dx
// set cursor start register to 0b00000000 to disable cursor
movb $0x00, %al
outb %dx
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Nothing changes. Is something wrong with the output command? How can I change the vga registers without int 0x10?

Comment: According to [the reference I googled](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/crtcreg.htm#0A) you should set it to `0x20` not `0x00`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for the response, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You might need to use port `0x3d4` and `0x3d5` depending on the address setup.

Comment: @Jester that did the trick. Thank you so much